# Using Backbone.js & Underscore, how to get a count of items from the model?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a notifications model for notifications

```
// MODEL
NotificationModel = App.BB.Model.extend({
    defaults : {}
});


// COLLECTION
NotificationCollection = App.BB.Collection.extend({
    model: NotificationModel,
    url: '/notifications',

    initialize : function() {
        var me = this;
        me.fetch();
    }

});
```

The collection is fetching from the server correctly and has the following fields (id, read) where read is true or false.

How can I get the total number count of items that are read == false? ... Unread item count?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A structured solution would be to create these methods in your collection:

```
read: function() {
    return this.filter(function(n) { return n.get('read'); });
},

unread: function() {
    return this.filter(function(n) { return !(n.get('read')); });
}
```

If you need the count, you can just add `.length` to the end of the method.

Answer (score 7):

Using the underscore's [`filter` method](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) and general JavaScript `.length` schould do it.

Backbone's documentation has [an example of `filter`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods), you just need to return read equals false.

```
var unread = Notes.filter(function(note) {
    return note.get("read") === false; 
}).length;
```

submitting from my mobile phone, sorry for the brief answer

Answer (score 0):

Backbone Collection's [`where` method](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) might be of use.

```
var read = this.where({ read: true });
var unread = this.where({ read: false });
```

This doesn't work if `read` isn't `true` or `false` -- in that case, you should use `filter` as the other answers suggest.