# Backbone.js getting a list to ensure only one instance of a certain model exists

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Forgive me, I am new to backbone, and the MVC javascript concept.

So, I am making a comments system:

```
createComment: function () {
        // create new comment model

        var comment = new CommentModel({});

        // render form view right after new button
        var formview = new FormView({model: comment});
        this.$el.after(formview.render().$el);

        // add saved model to collection after form was submitted successfully
        formview.on('success', this.handleFormSuccess, this);

        // finally, return false to stop event propagation
        return false;
    },
```

What I can't understand is how to get a list of comments which have been rendered, but have not been sent to the collection. See, I want to ensure that only one comment box is opened at once.

My approach is to do a check to see how many comments are open, and close everyone except the current model.

[Using Backbone.js & Underscore, how to get a count of items from the model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529791/using-backbone-js-underscore-how-to-get-a-count-of-items-from-the-model) seems to give advice for how to do this *after* the model hits a collection.

I am very new with backbone, so it is entirely possible I am in the exact wrong direction with this.

How do I get the list?

Comment: 'Success' is not a trigger. Should be 'sync'

Answer (score 0):

As Joe suggested, I think your problem is this line:

```
formview.on('success', this.handleFormSuccess, this);
```

However, I don't think his suggestion (of changing "success" to "sync") will work either, because `formview` is a *View*, not a *Model* or *Collection*, so it doesn't even have an `on` method.

What does have an `on` method is the view's element, so you can do:

```
formview.$el.on('success', this.handleFormSuccess, this);
```

Two problems with that though:

1. jQuery is lame and doesn't let you set the context like that
2. "success" isn't a form event; you want this code to trigger on "submit"

so to fix those two issues you need to change the line to:

```
formview.$el.on('submit', _(this.handleFormSuccess).bind(this));
```

Alternatively you could also call:

```
_(this).bindAll('handleFormSuccess');
```

in `FormView`'s `initialize`, which would make it so that you don't need to bind `this.handleFormSuccess)`:

```
formview.$el.on('submit', this.handleFormSuccess);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: P.S. You could avoid having to deal with binding altogether if you made `handleFormSuccess` a method of `FormView` instead of whatever view its on curently.  In that case you could just use `events: 'submit': 'handleFormSuccess') to take eliminate the need for that line entirely.